# query with multiple join/exist on the same relation with different where clause

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

here is my table

[image]
i want `product_id` that have both these conditions

```
 `f_id` = '4' and `value` in ('10', '11', '12', '13' )
```

and

```
 `f_id` = '10' and `value` in ('34')
```

which would be `product_id : 11`
here is my query

```
$products = Product::whereHas('ProductFilter' , function($q) use ($filter_groups){

        foreach($filter_groups as $k=>$v)
        $q->where('f_id' , $k )->whereIn( 'value' ,$v );

    })->get();
```

which will result in this query

```
select * from `products` where exists 

( 
  select * from `product_filters` where 
 `product_filters`.`product_id` = `products`.`id` and 
 `f_id` = '4' and `value` in ('10', '11', '12', '13' )   and 
 `f_id` = '10' and `value` in ('34')

)
```

but there is no relations between `f_id` and `value` and it wont return any result

basically what i want is this query

```
select * from `products` where exists 

( 
  select * from `product_filters` where 
 `product_filters`.`product_id` = `products`.`id` and 
 `f_id` = '4' and `value` in ('10', '11', '12', '13' )  

)
and exists 
( 
  select * from `product_filters` where 
 `product_filters`.`product_id` = `products`.`id` and 
 `f_id` = '10' and `value` in ('34')

)
```

Comment: You may want to use with() or load() method

Comment: select * from `product_filters` where 
 `f_id` = '4' and `value` in ('10', '11', '12', '13' )   and 
 `f_id` = '10' and `value` in ('34')                          what is the result of this query ?

Comment: @krishnpatel f_id cant be both 4 and 10 so it will not return any result .. .basically these conditions wont return anything in the same subquery

Comment: ok  where (f_id = '4' and value in ('10', '11', '12', '13' ) ) or ( f_id = '10' and value in ('34') ) use this condition

Comment: @krishnpatel i want products that have both these conditions if i use `or` it'll return the product even if it has one of those conditions

Comment: @hretic have you check my updated ans ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query = Product::where([]);
foreach($filter_groups as $k=>$v)
$query->whereHas('ProductFilter' , function($q) use ($k , $v ){
        $q->where('f_id' , $k )->whereIn( 'value' ,$v );
    })

$products = $query->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

you should write other condition as **subquery**

```
select * from `products` where exists 

( 
  select * from `product_filters` where 
 `product_filters`.`product_id` = `products`.`id` and 
  (`f_id` = '4' and `value` in ('10', '11', '12', '13' ) ) and  `product_filters`.`product_id` in (select product_id from product_filters where `f_id` = '10' and `value` in ('34') )    
)
```

Comment: i want products that have both these conditions if i use or it'll return the product even if it has one of those conditions

Comment: thanx but i want eloquent code not raw query i've produced an raw query that will work at the end of my question ..... apart from that  filters are dynamic and may change , so now they are 2 group of conditions next time there might be more .... so i should be able to write query them in a  loop

Comment: you can also add sub query  using loop.